# Regex to get content in the last occurrence of brackets in the most outer level

Tags: .net, regex

I have a string:
Example(123) (**Example (123)**)

I'm trying to get the string in bold. Currently I have this regex:
(?<=().+?(?=))

The regex works most of the time to get the text in brackets, but not when there's more than one occurrences with nested brackets.

Please advise how can I fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: I need a regex that will get me the values in bold:

Hello World (**Hello World (123)**)
Hello World (**Hello World**)

Comment: this is not to be done with regex, rather it should be done with simple programming logic ....

Answer (score 0):

You would need a recursive regex for proper matching. This one would work:

```
\(\w+\s*(?R)*[^()]*\)
```

[regex101 test](https://regex101.com/r/gR7s0m/3)

Issues:

- With just 1 pattern matching you will always get the outer parentheses.
- It is not anchored to the end of the string. I just don't know how can I achieve it. So you will need to grab the last match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\([a-zA-Z\s]+\s\([0-9]+\)
```

Updated code:

```
\([\w\s]*\(*[\w\s]*[()]*[\w\s]*\)\)
```

test [here](https://regex101.com/r/gR7s0m/5)

Comment: This works for the example above, but not for all cases.

I would like a regex that returns me the value in the last set of outer brackets, example, if I have "any_string_abc (anything) (**any_string (whatever)(whatever123)**)", I would like to get "any_string (whatever)(whatever123)"

Answer (score -1):

Try the following Solution to find the last occurrence of the bracket ")":

```
\)($)
```